# Hosting a web service with asp.net for iPhone application

Tags: c#, iphone, asp.net, ios, web-services

we got a server at my job (windows server 2003 with sql server 2005) 
Now i need to deploy a web service that will be consume in a iPhone application...
I am very new to .net and i really don't know how to set this web service online. 
I have created a asp.net web service c# app and i want it to be accessible remotely so i can consume it thought my iPhone app. If you have any tutorial or tricks to do this! Help. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here are couple of tutorials:

[For SOAP Services](http://www.dizzey.com/development/consuming-asp-net-web-services-in-ios-part1/)

[For Rest Service](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/connecting-the-iphone-with-aspnet-web-pages)

Both of these use JSON for data and use a third party library like [JSONKit](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/), since native iPhone libraries don't have JSON support.

Edit:

As @MishieMoo mentioned iOS 5 built-in api supports JSON.  For completeness I have added link to [iOS5 tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5).

Comment: Actually in iOS5 there is native JSON support. And there are enough users running iOS5 that apps can now only support iOS5 and higher.

Comment: @MishieMoo I have not looked at iOS5.  Thanks.  I will update the answer